# How to put filtered DynamoDB records to SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am working on a use-case where I need to take a complete dump of a DynamoDB table, filter to get the relevant records, and the publish each record to a SQS queue as a different message.

I don't think DynamoDB streams is good for my use-case as I need to take a periodic dump of the table and it doesn't have to be only when a record is updated/modified.

I have explored some options like Lambda, but I am skeptical if we'll be able to complete all of this in under 15 mins as the total records might be over 2 million and the relevant records for which I want to create a SQS message will be around 500K.

I have also explored AWS Glue which would help in filtering, but I am unable to find any info if AWS glue can publish individual records to SQS.

Any help appreciated as to which pattern makes sense and would be the best for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Its right that Lambda functions will not be the suitable choice for this scenario. You can use AWS Batch/EMR/Glue to perform the filtering and push to SQS.

All you need is to use boto3 client for SQS within Glue Job and publish the messages in queue.

```
import boto3

# Create SQS client
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
queue_url = 'SQS_QUEUE_URL'

# Send message to SQS queue
response = sqs.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MessageBody=message_body,
    MessageAttributes=message_attributes
)
```